# Dynamic Tabbed UI with Ember.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm working on an Ember.js application and one of my requirements is to design a tabbed UI with Bootstrap v3. I've been using EmberJS in production for two months now so I'm something of a beginner. I've spent some time on the internet searching on the subject but haven't been able to find any useful information yet.

I need to be able to render my routes into a Tab Control, each tab pane will have its own controller/template/view and when i close tab panes such objects should be disposed. So that when i open them up again, the controller instance is reset etc.

How would one implement this design? What is the best way to have a dynamic Tabbed UI with routing in Ember.js?

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I have exactly the same requirement and I'm also stuck as to the best way to implement this in Ember.js. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with.

Create your tabs as nested routes:

**router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('tabs', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('tab-one', { path: '/' });
    this.route('tab-two');
  });
});
```

Add your tab links and outlet for the nested routes in the Tabs route template:

**tabs.hbs**

```
<main class="container">
  <h1>Tabs</h1>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    {{#link-to 'tabs.tab-one' tagName="li"}}
      <a href={{view.href}}>Tab One</a>
    {{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to 'tabs.tab-two' tagName="li"}}
      <a href={{view.href}}>Tab Two</a>
    {{/link-to}}
  </ul>
  {{outlet}}
</main>
```

This will allow you to have separate Controllers and Templates for each of your tabs.